# How to download google map and use it offline in my application

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am developing an Android app using Google Maps API, users mostly use my app in the situation that there is no internet connection .
now i am searching for a way to download map when user want and use offline map when there is no more internet connection . Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5896100/12034846

Answer (score 0):

You need to check OSM. They provide an offline map service.
You can create your offline map server 
[OSM Map](https://www.openstreetmap.org)